# Apoyo con relaciones de bases de datos, php, JavaScript y ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, combobox

[image: Modelo entidad relación]

> La imagen del MER, esta simplificada, nada más para mostrar la relación para hacer los combobox dependientes. Diseño realizado en dbdiagram.io

Hola a todos, explico mi situación esta es el MER de un proyecto que se esta realizando donde se hace un registro de estudiante con su núcleo y carrera, por otra parte cuando se registra el núcleo mediante combobox dependientes muestra las carreras que están relacionadas con ese núcleo respectivo, hasta allí todo bien(el código usado funciona perfectamente). Pero el problema se presenta cuando una carrera puede estar en varios núcleos. De la manera como esta la relación tendría que hacer otro registro(nombre de carrera) en la tabla carrera para poder relacionar con otro núcleo.
Me explicó tengo un **Núcleo 1** que esta relacionado con una carrera(**administración**), pero al hacer otro registro puedo tener un **Núcleo 2** con la carrera(**administración**) y como los combobox son dependientes cuando escoja el **Núcleo 2** no me mostrara la carrera(**administración**), porque pertenece al **Núcleo 1**, según la relación establecida, para resolver tendría que crear otro registro en la tabla carrera con el nombre de **administración** para poder relacionarla con **Núcleo 2**: Esto no es lo que quiero porque se crea redundancia de los datos, como podría resolver esto con otro enfoque.
Navegando encontré este código el cual modifique según los requerimientos
**El cual trabaja muy bien**

````
    <!-- Combobox de Núcleo -->
                                <div>
                                    <?php
                                                
                                        // Consulta para obtener los datos del primer combobox
                                        $consulta1 = "SELECT * FROM nucleo";
                                        $resultado1 = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta1);
                                    ?>
                                    <!-- Combobox núcleo-->
                                    <select name="nucleo" id="nucleo">
                                        <option selected value="0" disabled>
                                            Sede o Extensión
                                        </option>
                                            <?php
                                                while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado1)):
                                            ?>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $row1['idnucleo'];?>" >
                                            <?php
                                                echo $row1['nucleo'];
                                            ?>
                                        </option>
                                        <?php 
                                            endwhile;
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
    
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Combobox carreras-->
                                    <select name="carrera" id="carrera">
                                        <option selected value="0" disabled>
                                            Carrera
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            // Cuando se cambia la opción del primer combobox
                                            $("#nucleo").change(function() {
                                                // Obtener el valor seleccionado
                                                var id = $(this).val();
                            
                                                // Limpiar las opciones del segundo combobox
                                                $("#carrera").html('<option selected value="4" disabled>Carrera</option>');
                            
                                                // Si se seleccionó una opción válida del primer combobox
                                                if(id > 0) {
                                                    // Obtener las opciones para el segundo combobox
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        type: 'POST',
                                                        url: 'obtener_opciones.php',
                                                        data: {id: id},
                                                        success: function(response) {
                                                        // Agregar las opciones al segundo combobox
                                                        $("#carrera").append(response);
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </div> ```
    
    **Código para obtener las opciones**
    ``` <?php
        // Conexión a la base de datos
        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    
        // Verificar la conexión
        if (!$conexion) {
            die("La conexión a la base de datos falló: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    
        // Obtener el valor enviado por AJAX (validar y escapar)
        $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['id']) : '';
    
        // Consulta para obtener los datos del segundo combobox (usar consulta preparada)
        //$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM carrera WHERE fk_nucleo_nu = ?"; 
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM carrera WHERE fk_nucleo = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consulta);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
        // Obtener el resultado de la consulta
        $resultado2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
        // Generar las opciones para el segundo combobox
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row2['idcarrera'].'">'.$row2['carrera'].'</option>';
        }
    
        // Cerrar la conexión y liberar recursos
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
     ```

Que podría hacer. cualquier ayuda sería agradecida
````

Comment: Si la relacion carrera nucleo es muchos a muchos (una carrera en muchos nucleos, un nucleo en muchas carreras) entonces, te falta una tabla intermedia carrera_nucleo.. y tu usuario, se conecta a esa tabla por el id_carrera_nucleo... como lo planteas, es un problema de base de datos